# extract a url from html page in java

Tags: java, html

I wanted to extract a url from a html page which html code can look like [paste.ubuntu.com/7014841](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7014841/) (it seems too long to post it here because it has thousands of lines of code).

I would like to extract a url to .3gp files like

```
http://dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/3GP/consert25tir-milad.3gp
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Extract what URL? From where?

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: use regular expressions... or something... or... don't know... your question is too vague

Comment: because this page has thousands of lines of code I cannot copy/paste in the question .this page: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7014841/

Comment: ex : I wanted to get : http://dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/3GP/consert25tir-milad.3gp

Comment: So, you want to extract value of link which points to any `.3gp` file. You are not interested in any text which looks like `http://whatever/something.3gp` if it is not in `<a href="...">...</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract value of `href` attribute from `<a href="...">..</a>` anchor you can simply use HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Code example of how to select all images which are `.png` files.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();

Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");

//After this just iterate over selected elements 
//and extract values you are interested in like 

for (Element png : pngs)
    System.out.println(png.attr("src"));
```

Now this should give you idea how to extract `.3gp` from links.

Comment: with .png is ok, but with .3gp or .mp4 does not worked :  Elements pngs = doc.select("a[href$=.3gp]");
    
for (Element png :pngs)
        System.out.println(png.attr("href"));

Comment: Strange, I used code from your comment on HTML you provided and it works for me. I suspect that this HTML code can be generated by JavaScript and when you are connecting to your page there is no `3gp` links yet, before JS kicks in. Try printing content of `doc` object to see what HTML code Jsoup sees and parses.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of the html file line by line,

```
    String extract = "";
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("page.html");
    String val = fin.readLine();
    while (val != null) {
        if (val.contains("http://")) {
            extract = val;
            break;
        } else {
            val = fin.readLine();
        }
    }
```

If any line of the html code contains http sequence it is treated as a link.